# How is multi-threading different in a Java based Web Application vs Stand-alone Java Application

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications

I am fairly new to Java and my experience is limited to Web Based Applications running on a Web Container (Jboss in my case).

Am I correct in saying that for Web Applications the web container takes care of multi-threading? If so, can I introduce new treads in a Web Based applications? Is there any advantage in doing so and in what scenario one would need to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Most web containers make application they run multi-threaded, since containers implement 'multi-threaded servlet model'. So, your application (code of your servlets) already being run by several threads, therefore, it must be thread-safe (you must use proper synchronization when accessing shared data, such as your servlet class' instance fields, etc.)

It's perfectly legal to launch new threads from within your web applications. For example, you may need it to launch some long-running task (registration of user in database which ends in email sending, or calculation of `PI` up to 100000th decimal place) and close user HTTP request immediately after that, making user's browser finish loading given URL.

Answer (score 4):

The web application server tends to create a new thread for each request. As such if two suers are filling the form and submitting it at the same time, you can be rest assured that both request are sent to the server using **separate threads**. The number of concurrent users accessing any particular page will actually determine the load the page can handle.

As far as creating new threads are concerned. You can certainly create new threads inside the application using the conventional java methods to create a new thread.

Generally you would like to create a new thread in case you want to perform an **async task** and does not want the **user to wait for the output**. Say suppose insertion of large data in DB which is nowhere related to user will generally be written in thread.

Also, in case where you intend to **perform long running task in the background**, the code is generally written inside a thread.

At times, **there are requirement that the user accessing the page and requesting for something also needs to be inside a thread at your server end**. E.g. trying to access a printer. IN that case you also need to ensure that your code is written inside a thread and you have properly synchronized the method.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in saying that for Web Applications the web container takes care of multi-threading?

Most of the Severs are multithreaded to handle multiple request concurrently.

> can I introduce new treads in a Web Based applications?

**Yes** you can. It depends on your requirement .

> Is there any advantage in doing so and in what scenario one would need to do that?

If there is a time taking  job which can be done asynchronously in to parts then use multiple threads.

**e.g.** on a request you have to read a huge file and dump in to database. In such case you can use multiple threads to read line by line and insert in to DB.

*As I said it depends.*

Comment: Thanks @amicngh. Any example of a requirement where one would want to introduce code level multi-threading in a web application?

Comment: One example @kapricanon, is some sort of database query that might take a minute to process.  You don't want your web request to return in a minute so you fork the background thread to do the query and store the results.  Then you web request can check on the status of the request and display the results when the background thread is done.

Answer (score 1):

Most web application servers handle incoming requests on their own thread. That means if your server handles 5 requests concurrently it's running 5 threads.

That's *usually* enough multithreading to sufficiently exercise a medium-to-big server.

If, however, you've got an atypical workload (for example few requests, but each requests includes heavy computation), then introducing your own multi-threading *on top of this* may be worth the investment.